# Tomcat gets stopped as I run my web app on it

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am bit confused with the concept of RESTfull web service.

As I run my web application on server my server gives error.

Here is my `UserService.java`

```
package com.service;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/user/service")
public class UserService {

    @PUT
    public void createUser() {}

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void getUser() {
        System.out.println("Heyy, it's getting the user");
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void updateUser() {
        System.out.println("Heyy, it's updating the user");
    }

    @DELETE
    public void deleteUser() {}

    @Path("/special")
    public SpecialUser getSpecialUser() {
        return new SpecialUser();
    }

}
```

And here is my `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>RestWSdemo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>

    <servlet-name>webService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webServices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I think something is there I am missing in `web.xml`.

If I start my server without adding these resource, it gets start normally on `localhost:8080`.

But as I run my application on server, I am getting these error on `console` with a error message.
[image: ServerError]

Please somebody help me out from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servlet mapping does not match your servlet name, one is called `webService`, the other `webServices`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webService</servlet-name>
    <!-- ... -->
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webServices</servlet-name>
    <!-- ... -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

Make sure that both names are the same.

For what it's worth: the error message indicating the root cause of your problem is the one that appears before the one in your screenshot. Don't post screenshots, but include the complete stacktrace in your question instead.

Comment: Ohh my stupidity, I thought the error dialogue box will help to find out the error, so I've added the pic. Well okay, I'll follow your suggestions. Thanks a lot.